# Difference between Build Pipeline and Deployment Pipeline

Tags: deployment, build-server, development, azure-devops

If somebody could explain this in the simplest of terms I would appreciate it. I'm trying to understand the differences between the two if there are any.

Comment: build is like compiling or create packages and so on, deployment is deploy, look for ci/cd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) build is putting the engine together.  Compile, package, test and put into inventory.

2) deploy is install in a car, put gas in and start up.  Spin up an instance in a container, server, runtime interpreter and make available for production use.